# Updating Solr from 4.0 to 4.4

Tags: solr

I have updated my Solr installation from 4.0 to 4.4 by exchanging the two folders `contrib` and `dist`. Then I have restartet the solr server.

But my Solr Admin page still sais:

```
solr-spec   4.0.0.2012.08.06.22.50.47
solr-impl   4.0.0-BETA 1370099 - rmuir - 2012-08-06 22:50:47
lucene-spec 4.0.0-BETA
lucene-impl 4.0.0-BETA 1370099 - rmuir - 2012-08-06 22:44:25
```

What do I have to exchange additionally? There is only my project folder left, which I thought should be untouched...

Comment: how about the war ?? which still would refer to the 4.0 libraries ? To be on safer side, why not just copy your folders to 4.4. Also you may want to check on the Index compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `webapps/solr.war` with the new file and remove all files from `solr-webapp` (war is unpacked to this folder on first run).